# Get Twitter User ID from Email Address

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to get Twitter ID's from Email Addresses for a crm application. Everywhere I'm reading, says it was a feature that was removed from the twitter api a while ago due to farming.

However, I notice that SocialBro (and others) still offer this feature - e.g. upload a csv of email addresses and get a returned list of twitter user objects.

Can anyone shed any light on how this is being achieved if its not possible via the API?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try fullcontact.com

You can get hundreds of social media accounts of one person using their email, facebook or twitter. You can access it through their API.

It's not always complete, but it's far easier than trying to find it on our own.

Answer (score 0):

This feature isn't available in the Twitter Public API :
source : https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5232

you've to have access to a business API which let you have access to it.

cheers